# mean normalization for each column of pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

To implement mean normalization for each column of pandas data frame.

code:

```
def transformation(x,mean,std):
   return (x-mean)/std

def read_input(path):

   data = pd.read_csv(path)
   for each_column in data.columns:
       mean = data[each_column].mean(); std = data[each_column].std()
       data[each_column].apply(transformation(self,mean,std))

   print (data)
   return data
```

The error is transformation function has three parameters. Assuming the first parameter as each value in the respective column of the data frame, I used the apply function with self. But it is not working. Any suggestions please?

Comment: Just use `(data - data.mean()) / data.std()`  that's the beauty of pandas.

Comment: @ayhan I am not able to understand your solution. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @ayhan got it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think a working solution has been mentioned in comments.

To understand a bit further why your code does not work.
[Apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) function will not modify existing df but return calculated series or dataframe.

Simple analogy: x=1; x+1; x value will not change.
Another solution could be:

```
data[each_column] = data[each_column].apply(transformation(self,mean,std))
```